# ZF2 RememberMe expires after closing Browser

Tags: php, zend-framework2, session-cookies

I want a "remember-me" cookie for my login form and get it work until I reopen the browser. I am using the Zend Framework 2 to get it done.

I set up a form with a checkbox and have this in my controller after validating the form:

```
$userSession = new Container("test");

$sessionManager = $userSession->getManager();
$sessionManager->rememberMe(1209600);
$sessionManager->start();
```

In the module.config.php I have the following settings for the session:

```
'session' => array(
    'name' => 'Test_SESSION',
    'save_path' => realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\Workspace\test\data\session'),
    'remember_me_seconds' => 1209600,
    'cookie_lifetime' => 1209600,
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_httponly' => true,
),
```

And finally in module.php:

```
$session = new SessionConfig();
$session->setOptions($this->serviceLocator->get("config")["session"]);
```

I searched through the web for any advises and tried something, but at least when I close the browser the cookie is deleted. Firefox settings of deleting cookies were checked also, so they won't be automatically deleted. Does any one has a successful solution or hint?

Edit: When I take the code of newtake and add `$sessionManager->rememberMe();` to it, the session is still alive after closing browser, but I can't login anymore even the login process is successfully done. Anyone heard from this curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Need setup `SessionConfig` to `SessionManager`. It is my config

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Session\SessionManager' => function ($sm) {
            $sessionConfig = new \Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig();
            $sessionConfig->setOptions([
                'use_cookies' => true,
                'gc_maxlifetime' => 1728000,
                'cookie_lifetime' => 1728000,
                'name' => 'COOKIE_NAME',
            ]);

            $sessionManager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager($sessionConfig);
            $sessionManager->start();
            return $sessionManager;
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how can I make use of this service in the controller?

Comment: Session will be started, but still deleted after closing browser :/

Comment: @HansMartin Using is simple just need create an object from `Container`. Example `$session = new Container('container-name');`

Comment: @HansMartin This config and Container object it's all. You don't need another code for session.

Comment: I got it now, but there are some questions left...the rememberMe function does work now, but it only works when I add this `$session = new Container("user"); $session->username = $userName;$session->getManager()->rememberMe();` in my service. Why doesn't it work when I write `$sessionManager->rememberMe()` in config and start session like you suggest without `$session->getManager()->rememberMe();`?

Comment: @HansMartin You have parameters `gc_maxlifetime` and `cookie_lifetime` in session config. Don't need use `$session->getManager()->rememberMe()`